Defining filter of QgsMapLayerComboBox as layer without geometry with PyQGIS
How to define the filter of a QgsMapLayerComboBox as a layer without geometry with PyQGIS?

Below I share examples of how to filter points, lines, polygons and raster layers. But layers without geometry I don't know.
self.settings.CMBRNFs.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)
self.settings.CMBPIPES.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.LineLayer)
self.settings.CMBARRU.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer)
self.settings.CMBMDE.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.RasterLayer )


QgsMapLayerProxyModel.NoGeometry. Read the docs

https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#a6507a4bb8d0f5eff8a488213bb98db28
